# Single function with two ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function with two Ajax Get call. after success two Ajax have different function for success handling

```
       function get_power_mgt_settings() {
         window.mv.do_ajax_call('GET',power_mgt.get_spin_down_url{},'xml',true,show_spin_down_settings, window.mv.handle_error);

         window.mv.do_ajax_call('GET',power_mgt.get_power_schedule_url{},'xml',true,show_power_schedule_settings, window.mv.handle_error);
    }  



    function show_power_schedule_settings(data) {
    ----some data to populate table<br>
    }



    function show_spin_down_settings(data){
    -----some data to populate table<br>
    }
```

My problem is that , i have 2 submit button when i click submit button it call a function for saving data. In first submit button after submitting data i need to reload show_power_schedule_settings() only.
In second submit button after submitting data i need to call  `show_spin_down_settings()` only. But actually this two function is merged with single function named `get_power_mgt_settings()`. So my doubt is how can i call only one function from this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to separate out the function you need for easy usage.

Comment: What you said is right but i Love to optimize my code as much i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give parameter in `get_power_mgt_settings(params);`
example:

```
function get_power_mgt_settings(type) {
  if(type="firstSubmit"){
      window.mv.do_ajax_call('GET',power_mgt.get_spin_down_url{},'xml',true,show_spin_down_settings, window.mv.handle_error);
}else if(type="secondSubmit"){
     window.mv.do_ajax_call('GET',power_mgt.get_power_schedule_url{},'xml',true,show_power_schedule_settings, window.mv.handle_error);
}else{
  alert("whatever what doyou want");
}
}
```

and call with `get_power_mgt_settings("secondSubmit");` that is just execution `window.mv.do_ajax_call('GET',power_mgt.get_power_schedule_url{},'xml',true,show_power_schedule_settings, window.mv.handle_error);`

Comment: Thanks dude. one more doubt how can i get these two ajax call while page loading.

Comment: function pageloading(){ get_power_mgt_settings(); } after did as per u said now am not get any value in page loading

Comment: hmm its fine ..i just forgot basic of function, what i learned in my pg. Your answer is perfect. Thanks